# Specflow - What is the testing type which is covered as part of feature file/BDD

Tags: c#, automated-tests, bdd, specflow

This might be a sort of stupid question, but still trying to find my understanding on BDD Specflow .
In my experience across Specflow - seen different companies using Specflow to capture scenarios/test across-

- Component level Testing
- Functional Testing
- System Integration Testing
- Regression Testing

So say for example my feature below for System Integration test coverage-

```
Given An active account exists
When I  fill up a form & submit a new investment (submitted but not approved)
Then Check the record inserted into a specific table
And new transaction displayed in Holdings report
And new transaction not displayed in cash balance report (as not yet approved)
```

In some companies they practice to break it down further-Component

Separate out above scenario to 2 features like below -

1. One validating till inserted to database

   ```
   Given An active account exists
   When I  fill up a form & submit a new investment (submitted but not approved)
   Then Check the record inserted into a specific table
   ```
2. The other Checking the reports

   ```
   Given A new Investment is recorded
           When we run the reports
           Then new transaction displayed in Holdings report
           And new transaction not displayed in cash balance report (as not yet approved)
   ```

Which of the above is right way of writing Specflow features? Whats best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the better way as per BDD guidelines is second option that you wrote above. Because you are somewhat covering a different behavior in second scenario. Anytime scenario called for two when-then statements it is better to have separate scenarios. Check out [here](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/) , this exactly addresses your point. You can even check  tenses and see if they are correct in your scenarios above.

Comment: Thanks @user1207289. If we go with option 2 above , just to make our test more stable - we need to execute test 1 of option 2 as first step of test 2. In above example- creating a new investment either filling form or direct dB insert in step Given a new investment exists and then check in reports. Won’t the first test be covered in second? Repitative?

Comment: in your second scenario `Given` , just check the end state of the first test  i.e investment is recorded .  You don't have to record the investment rather just check that it is there.